# Безпрерывная музыка при переходе с одной страницы сайта на другую

Tags: html, css

Что нужно сделать, чтобы на сайте играла музыка и при переходе с одной страницы сайта на другую музыка играла не переставая?

Comment: [Строчка, которая изменит мир][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/16774/

Comment: А как на примере ее можно применить?

Comment: @Kamiplus, можно сайт сделать на AJAX'е, а для того, чтобы совершались как бы переходы в адресной строке, использовать эту штуку по ссылке выше. Как в синенькой соц.сети.

Comment: хм, я как то пытался реализовать это при помощи iframe..
ток надоело и забил=)

Answer (score 1):

Либо открыть в новом окне страницу с проигрывателем, либо делать сайт на Flash/Javascript дабы реализовать возможность навигации без перезагрузки страницы.

Answer (score 0):

посмотри как у них реализовано [радио](http://www.zaycev.fm/).
очень интересно, и на мой взгляд подходит тебе.